# Using read.csv2 - how can I shorten path to a Windows directory / file?

Tags: r, file, read.table

I have many files in csv in which it is necessary to read the data, I am 
   using read.csv2, but shortening the route gives me a problem.

Here an example

```
  data2 <- read.csv2("C:/Desktop/CONSULT/test/prueba_pl.csv")
```

I did this query:

```
 data2 <- read.csv2("../test/prueba_pl.csv")
```

but it's throwing me an error, maybe I'm forgetting something

Answer (score 1):

You can set your working directory first and then use `~` in the file path to shorten it.

For your example -

```
setwd("C:/Desktop/CONSULT")

data2 <- read.csv2("~/test/prueba_pl.csv")
```

Comment: Or  using setwd("C:/Desktop/CONSULT/test") and then calling the file by read.csv2("prueba_pl.csv"). That would work too right?

Comment: @Prometheus Yes, that should work too but I just chose to stick with OP's example.

Comment: @Prometheus It is recommended that you do not `setwd` in most cases though. See https://github.com/jennybc/here_here.